# How can two identically named files exist in the same place on linux

Tags: php, linux, permissions

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKDvR.jpg]
.

1. I'm not a novice in linux
2. I created  a bunch of files with php using file_put_contents()
3. I can't view the created files via browser
4. I can view the files from the ftp but can't change/download/delete them(it says file not found)
5. I have tried to SSH as root and change the permissions and user/group from there, but it says file not found
6. I have tried opening the files using php with file_get_contents(); it says file not found
7. I can rename or download the files from File Manager
8. I did a fair amount of research on this but can't find a solution
9. I managed to create another file with the same name in the same directory via php, as per screenshot.

As you can see things are very confusing, especially for someone like me that doesn't know too much about linux. But I know one thing, on any OS there can not exist in the same place and time two files with the same name. It's not an ftp error because I checked with file manager too.

Comment: it can happen that one of the filename has special character which is not visible in browser or your file browser is just stripping it.

Comment: Files are not identical ( size differs, according to listing ). Their names look like identical. Maybe there's space or tab at the end, or it is disk error? What about shell output?

Comment: You are not really looking at the directory. If you can ssh to the server, do a directory listing from there.

Comment: Can you see them via ssh when you `ls`?

Comment: If it says "not found" when you try to access it in shell, it probably means that filename you type in is not exactly name of the file you're trying to access, as outlined in comments above. At worst could be filesystem error, but I don't think so in this case. if it's remotely mouted partition - some FS create confusion with upper/lowercase, depending on configuration.

Comment: Sometimes a special dot character that resembles a dot, may not be a do after all, I've seen that before.

Comment: Is it your ftp client being tardy?

Comment: Q: Are your `.png` files coming in from an outside source?

Comment: I'ts probably caused by some not visible white͘-spaces or͘̕ m̴a̷̛͟y̸̢bę̕͞  ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴*ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: I just tried to ssh and see the files and UltimateProgrammer_BR is right, there is a line break at the end of the file "1.png\n". I would never found that. Thanks for the help. Now the question is how can I change back the names, I can't do it manually because there are a lot of files

Comment: @razvan Once you find a solution, posting it as an answer will definitely be beneficial to others, am sure. First time I ever heard of that. Cheers

Comment: I figured it out. I have a file with all the path files on the server and I can just add \n  at the end and use that to modify the files. Thanks again. I think  shiplu.mokadd.im deserves the points because he answered first what was the issue. If you would to post as a regular question I would be happy to accept it as the right answer.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im See what `razvan` wrote. Good work! I'm going to remember that one. Cheers

Comment: Added the comment as an answer as per comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can happen when one of the file name has special character which is not visible.

Either its not visible in the browser or your file browser is just stripping this character. Many software does it to beautify the output.

Comment: Indeed, this can be a limitation of the program that does list the files. Back in the days Windows would display a file named "foo.jpg<lots of whitespace>.exe" as "foo.jpg" - it was a common trick used by script kiddies to spread malware.